# MySQL - How do I set default value in an equation to 0?

Tags: mysql

I use this formula to calculate

difference (v2-v1) and

percentage difference (v2-v1)/v1

v1 and v2 can be null in which case the result would also be null. how do I put a default value of 0 in there?

Comment: Can you share more information or some code which you've tried?

Comment: Why not use `CASE` for this?

Answer (score 0):

You may:

1. Use COALESCE() function in the expression:

```
SELECT ... ,
       COALESCE(v2 / v1 -1, 0) AS percentage_difference,
       ...
FROM ...
```

2. Add generated column to the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE ... ( ... ,
                   percentage_difference DOUBLE(10, 4) AS (COALESCE(v2 / v1 -1, 0)),
                   ... );
```

and respectively

```
SELECT ... ,
       percentage_difference,
       ...
FROM ...
```

PS. Do not forget to add check constraint `CHECK (v2 != 0)` to the table structure for to avoid 'Division by zero' error. In both cases.